# Need to capture UDP packets on a Linux router, modify them and send them to the original destination

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm dealing with a legacy application that can't be touched. It sends UDP packets to addresses calculated from a client ID (yes, really: its basically something like 192.168.0.x, where x is the client ID, just a bit more complex).

I have a Linux machine running, that forwards the packets from the legacy app to their final destinations. I need to capture these packets in an application, do something (read: encrypt them) and then send the newly encrypted packets to their original destinations. What I have in mind is some kind of iptables magic that changes the destination address of incoming packets so that they get locally delivered, but doesn't touch the outgoing packets. I don't need the original dest address, I can recreate it from the content of the packet.
Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all what you need is to redirect the received packets to the local machine, you can add a rule like the following in NAT table:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.4 -d 5.6.7.8 -p udp --dport 3333 -j REDIRECT
```

These numbers (IPs, and port) are just examples. You need to specify your own values, or you can omit them when not needed.

This rule will redirect all received UDP packets originated from IP `1.2.3.4` destined to `5.6.7.8` to port `3333`.

You need to have an application listening on this port number to do your processing and then send them to destination (you said you have a way to figure out the destination).

Answer (score 1):

So you asking for a men in the middle setup?
I would implement the following rule set:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport [yourportlegacy] -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport [yourportapp] -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport [yourportlegacy] -j REDIRECT --to-ports [yourportapp]
```

[yourportlegacy]=Destination Port of the packets send by the legacy app

[yourportapp]= Port your manipulating app is listening on the linux machine

With this ruleset you should be able to fetch packets with your app on the defined port. Later you can send them to the actual destination.

Comment: This is indeed what I was looking for. I tested it with netcat and a separate net namespace. Thank you and Khaled for pointing me into the right direction.